# ORMLite - How to handle result of join

Tags: android, ormlite

I have tables A, B, C, D, E and I'm doing inner join across them.
I need only partial data from results. For example, I need `A.name` column, `D.phoneNumber` column.

I'm using the method `join()`.

How should I handle the result? Should I go through all my classes, to get all the data I need? If yes, what is a simple way to do this, because going through all of that seems a bit complicated.

Should I create a class just for result and somehow map the result to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the ORMlite documentation you can only use join statement with the tables connected via foreign object field.

So the first approach as I see it is to use foreign object and retreive all the values you need. For example if you query you tables A and B with

```
QueryBuilder<A, Integer> aqb = aDao.queryBuilder();
QueryBuilder<B, Integer> bqb = bDao.queryBuilder();
List<A> results = aqb.join(bqb).query();

for (A a : results){
    String name = a.getName();
    String phone = a.getB().getPhone();
}
```

whereas A and B classes looks something like this:

```
....
public class A{
....
    @DatabaseField
    private String name;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private B b;
....        
    public B getB(){
        return b;
    }
....
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}

....
public class B{
....
    @DatabaseField
    private String phone;

    public String getPhone(){
        return phone;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about exactly this code will work, I just wanted to describe the idea.

As I know you can't query for the multiple tables at once.

See the [related ORMLite documentation](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_3.html#SEC39).
Join statements have been supported since version 4.42 of the library.

Comment: So what you are saying is basicly that I sould just go through all of classes A, B,C,D,E and I should retrieve values from whatever clasess I need?

If yes, then I would say it would be better to create custom SQL and not use ORM.

Comment: Generally - yes. The ORMlite is a light-weight library that simplifies most common sql operations. For things that you're doing is much more easy to use SQL request, retrieve Cursor and go through it.